# How to check variable value in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework

I would like to check the value of the outgoing variable whether it is 0 or 1. I tried below code to do the same but I am not able to check it. In below code `message` is a dictionary which contains values of `XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject`.

How to check the value of `outgoing` variable?

`message` dictionary contains:

```
bareJid = "(...not nil..)";
bareJidStr = "tester3@90.0.0.163";
body = "{\"Date\":\"14 Jun 2017\",\"Time\":\"4:21PM\",\"body\":\"hello\",\"filePath\":\"\",\"isImportant\":\"N\",\"isMine\":true,\"msgid\":\"167-36\",\"receiver\":\"tester1\",\"sender\":\"tester3\",\"senderName\":\"tester3\"}";
composing = 0;
message = "(...not nil..)";
messageStr = "<message xmlns=\"jabber:client\" to=\"tester1@90.0.0.163\" id=\"167-36\" type=\"chat\" from=\"tester3@90.0.0.163/Smack\"><body>{\"Date\":\"14 Jun 2017\",\"Time\":\"4:21PM\",\"body\":\"hello\",\"filePath\":\"\",\"isImportant\":\"N";
outgoing = 0;
streamBareJidStr = "tester1@90.0.0.163";
thread = "2066797c-4f79-48f3-bd04-30658ee35e9f";
timestamp = "2017-06-14 11:20:41 +0000";
```

When I debug the value of `outgoing` variable then Xcode shows the type of it is `Any?` and value of it is `some`.

```
let outgoing = messasge.value(forKey: "outgoing")
var isIncoming = true

if let og = outgoing as? Int {
    if og == 1 {
        isIncoming = false
    }
}
```

Comment: try let outgoing = messasge.value(forKey: "outgoing") as! Int, instead of let outgoing = messasge.value(forKey: "outgoing").

Comment: I tried it but it throws runtime error.

Comment: When Xcode shows the type of outgoing as Any? and value of it is some. Does it make sense that outgoing is pointer?

Comment: @samdroid message["outgoing"] value data type is string or int??

Comment: @Subramanian I could not able to understand the type of outgoing variable.     I retrieve data from XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject. When I debug it. It shows the type of outgoing variable = Any? and value = some.

Comment: Because you are checking Int. thats not working, may be it can be string

Comment: @Subramanian. I tried same with String also. no result.

Comment: @samdroid did you check is that Bool type? if not then try that also

Answer (score 2):

If your dictionary value data type is Anyobject then unwrap as NSNumber and convert to integer or bool

```
if let outgoing = message["outgoing"] {
       let convertedValue = Int(outgoing as! NSNumber)
        if convertedValue == 1 {
            isIncoming = false
            print("Incoming false")
        }
    }
```

**Example :**

```
 var messasge = [String: AnyObject]()
        messasge["outgoing"] = "1" as AnyObject;

        if let outgoing = messasge["outgoing"] {
           let convertedValue = Int(outgoing as! NSNumber)
            if convertedValue == 1 {
                print("Incoming false")
            }
        }
```

**message["outgoing"] value data type is `String` :**

```
 var messasge = [String: Any]()

  messasge["outgoing"] = "1" ;

 if let outgoing = messasge["outgoing"] as? String, outgoing == "1" {
     isIncoming = false
  }
```

**message["outgoing"] value data type is `Int` :**

```
 var messasge = [String: Any]()

 messasge["outgoing"] = 1 ;

 if let outgoing = messasge["outgoing"] as? Int, outgoing == 1 {
     isIncoming = false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let outgoing : String = messasge.value(forKey: "outgoing")
let og = Int(outgoing)
if og == 1
{// isIncoming = false
}
else
{
  //isIncoming = true
}
```